# Infinispan preload data from database table

Tags: java, caching, infinispan

How to preload data to infinispan local cache? I have a pre-existing application table that has key value pairs. I want infinispan to cache the data in the table and when i read/write data to cache, i want the underlying table to be in sync. Is it possible with infinispan?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628895/infinispan-file-store-with-pre-loaded-data#

Answer (score 1):

Infinispan stores the entries in SQL DB in a marshalled form (as there is no generic mapping between POJOs and SQL), and also needs to keep some metadata along. That's why the JDBC stores can't access existing DB structure.

There's also the JPA store which uses Hibernate ORM to access the DB and "marshall" the entries according to the JPA specification. So this may be an option for you.

Comment: I understand jpa-store that would work for my needs. I am looking for similar solution for a non-jpa kind of environment.

Comment: I have another question. Can i have jpa-store behave in a write-behind way?

Comment: Yes it can, write-behind functionality is independent of the cache store implementation.